# joining two tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm trying to join two tables(to get the OrderLines) and I'm geetting 0 records even if I manually checked if there is matching records and there is multiple records for each customerID that are matching the second DE

First DE
[image]

Second DE
[image]

This is the query that I'm using

```
SELECT

a.CustomerID,
a.OrderID,
a.OrderDate,
b.OrderLines

FROM
[First DE] as a
INNER JOIN
[Second DE] as b
ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

and this is the Target DE
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've also got a data type mismatch -- you're selecting `OrderLines` which is set to the max length (4000 characters), while in the target is only 50 characters.

The primary key on your target DE should probably be `CustomerID` and `OrderID`, not `CustomerID` and `OrderDate`.

I'd also switch your query up and select from `Second DE` and join to `First DE` -- "select any customer with an order" instead of "select any order with a customer."

```sql
SELECT
  a.CustomerID
, a.OrderID
, a.OrderDate
, b.OrderLines
FROM [Second DE] b
INNER JOIN [First DE] a ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
where a.orderID is not null
and b.orderlines is not null
/* target: Target DE */
/* action: overwrite */
```

**First DE**

- OrderDate, Date, non-nullable
- OrderID, Decimal(18,0), nullable
- CustomerID, Text(100), nullable

**Second DE**

- SubscriberKey, Text(254), non-nullable
- EmailAddress, EmailAddress, non-nullable
- CustomerID, Text(100), non-nullable
- OrderID, Decimal(18,0), non-nullable
- OrderLines, Text(max), non-nullable

**Target DE**

- OrderDate, Date, non-nullable
- OrderID, Decimal(18,0), **primary key, nullable**
- CustomerID, Text(100), **primary key, nullable**
- OrderLines, **Text(max)**, non-nullable
- SubscriberKey, Text(254), non-nullable

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adam Spriggs

Answer (score 0):

Is the query completing or erroring?
Do your required fields contain values? If required field dont contain a value the query will error and not populate the DE at all.

Comment: The query I think is completing. By required field do you mean if OrderLines contains data? If so, yes, it does